# Multiple Search Fields not working as expected

Tags: django, ajax

I have 3 search field(event_name, event_loc, event_date), while one of them filled it return all table data, while it has to be return one.

**views.py**

```
def searchEvent(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q_event_name = request.POST.get('event_name')
        q_event_loc = request.POST.get('event_loc')
        q_event_date = request.POST.get('event_date')

        # return JsonResponse(dict(events=list(Event.objects.values('name', 'info'))))

        return JsonResponse(
            serializers.serialize('json', Event.objects.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=q_event_name) | Q(info__icontains=q_event_loc) | Q(start_event_dt__icontains=q_event_date))),
            safe=False)
```

**custom.js**

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/searchevent/',
        data: {
            'event_name': event_name,
            'event_loc': event_loc,
            'event_date': event_date
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            event_html = '';
            for(var i in data){
            event_name = data[i]['fields']['name'];
            event_html = event_html + '<div class="col-md-4">' +
                '    <h5 class="card-title text-center pt-3">' + event_name + '</h5>' +
                '</div>';
            }
    document.getElementById("event-container").innerHTML = event_html;
        }
    });
```

for example, I have two event in my DB

1. name=aaa, loc=bbb, date=2019-01-01
2. name=ccc, loc=ddd, date=2018-01-01

in the search bar when I searched for only name field with aaa, it returns all of the two event, which i expected to return me only first event.

Comment: Could you do a print in your `def searchEvent(request)` method on  q_event_name, q_event_loc, q_event_date?

What are there values if they are "empty" (so if just one parameter is filled as you phrased it)

Comment: @RaiderR,   name:aaa
loc:
date:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Q-expressions to build up your query (or-conditions).

So your filter expression will translate to:

```
name__icontains=q_event_name OR info__icontains=q_event_loc OR start_event_dt__icontains=q_event_date
```

If `q_event_loc` is for example an empty string - `icontains` will match every `info` column which is not null.

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed "or" to "and". It solved.  `Q(name__icontains=q_event_name) & Q(info__icontains=q_event_loc) & Q(start_event_dt__icontains=q_event_date))),
            safe=False)`